# ADDS(operations with S suffix) -Arm

Tags: assembly, arm, register

This question was asked before here but in the answers I did get what i was looking for.

Consider this:

```
ADDS R0 RO R1
```

As far as I know to update the cpsr flags a subtraction has to be made. So after this instruction, is the result subtracted from RO or R1?

Edit:
This is what I understand

```
CMP RO R1
```

In this instruction, `R1` is subtracted from `R0` and based on the results the flags are updated. The thing I dont understand is in operations with S suffix the result after the operation like `eg ADDS  on the top` is it subtracted from `R0` or `R1` to update the flags or i got it all wrong?

Edit 2:

For example consider these instructions

```
mov r0, #1
mov r1, #6
tst r1, r0
bne 0x6000
```

From this example, the result of the tst instruction is 7(111 binary). In the branch instruction how can it branch with the NE condition code if there was no comparison between registers.

Comment: R0 == R0+R1 is the operation here not sure what subtraction you are referring to the S modifies the flags based on the result of operation

Comment: @blabb i have updated the question please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I Commented the operation here is R0 == R0+R1
the Current Program Status Register or
Application Program Status Register are modified based on the result

Assume for  example

R0 contains 0xffffffff (maximum possible 32 bit unsigned integer)
R1 contains 0x00000001

R0+R1 will be

```
>>> print(hex(0xffffffff+0x00000001))
0x100000000
>>>
```

the result is a 33bit or in other words the result is 0x0 and the 33<sup>rd</sup> bit is lost
since result is 0 N or Negative flag is not set **N=0**

again since result is 0 zero flag is set to 1 **Z=1**

the upper 33<sup>rd</sup> bit is lost so Carry flag is set **C==1**

signed or v flag doesn't not have any overflow (-1 + 1 ) == 0 so V flag is not set **V=0**

[this all are explained in this document](https://community.arm.com/arm-community-blogs/b/architectures-and-processors-blog/posts/condition-codes-1-condition-flags-and-codes)

there is a source code and demo also attached in the link

where adds and the cpsr details are retrieved by this assembly stub
you can use unicorn or unicorn based qiling to emulate these instruction

```
doADDS:
    @ Perform the operation, leaving the result in r0 to return it.
    adds    r0, r0, r1
    
    @ Get the APSR flags and dump them into flags (*r2).
    mrs     r3, CPSR
    str     r3, [r2]
    
    @ The recommended (interworking-compatible) return method:
    bx      lr
```

a sample emulation and cpsr flags using Qiling Framework

```
:\>type armshell.py
from qiling import *
from qiling.const import QL_VERBOSE

# 0x0000000000000000:  00 00 E0 E3    mvn  r0, #0
# 0x0000000000000004:  01 10 A0 E3    mov  r1, #1
# 0x0000000000000008:  01 00 90 E0    adds r0, r0, r1
# 0x000000000000000c:  00 F0 20 E3    nop
# 0x0000000000000010:  00 F0 20 E3    nop

shellcode = b"\x00\x00\xe0\xe3\x01\x10\xa0\xe3\x01\x00\x90\xe0\x00\xf0\x20\xe3\x00\xf0\x20\xe3"

ql = Qiling(
    code=shellcode,
    rootfs=r"F:\QILING\examples\rootfs\x8664_windows",
    ostype="linux",
    archtype="arm",
    verbose=QL_VERBOSE.DEBUG
)
ql.reg.cpsr = 0
ql.reg.r0 = 0
ql.reg.r1 = 0
print("registers before starting")
print("r0 = 0x{:x}".format(ql.reg.r0))
print("r1 = 0x{:x}".format(ql.reg.r1))
print("cpsr = 0x{:x}\n".format(ql.reg.cpsr))

for i in range(1, 5, 1):
    ql.run(0, len(shellcode), -1, i)
    print("r0 = 0x{:x}".format(ql.reg.r0))
    print("r1 = 0x{:x}".format(ql.reg.r1))
    print("cpsr = 0x{:x}\n".format(ql.reg.cpsr))
```

executed

```
:\>python armshell.py
[+]     Profile: Default
[+]     Set init_kernel_get_tls
registers before starting
r0 = 0x0
r1 = 0x0
cpsr = 0x0

r0 = 0xffffffff
r1 = 0x0
cpsr = 0x0

r0 = 0xffffffff
r1 = 0x1
cpsr = 0x0

r0 = 0x0
r1 = 0x1
cpsr = 0x60000000

r0 = 0x0
r1 = 0x1
cpsr = 0x60000000
```

the cpsr is set with bit 29,30 representing flags Z and C (Zero and Carry)

```
>>> hex(1<<30|1<<29)
'0x60000000'
>>>
```

feeding with a ladle

```
from qiling import *
from qiling.const import QL_VERBOSE

# 0x0000000000000000:  00 F0 20 E3    nop 
# 0x0000000000000004:  01 00 A0 E3    mov r0, #1
# 0x0000000000000008:  06 10 A0 E3    mov r1, #6
# 0x000000000000000c:  00 00 11 E1    tst r1, r0
# 0x0000000000000010:  FA 17 00 1A    bne #0x6000
# 0x0000000000000014:  00 F0 20 E3    nop 

shellcode = b"\x00\xf0\x20\xe3\x01\x00\xa0\xe3\x06\x10\xa0\xe3\x00\x00\x11\xe1\xfa\x17\x00\x1a\x00\xf0\x20\xe3"

ql = Qiling(
    code=shellcode,
    rootfs=r"F:\QILING\examples\rootfs\x8664_windows",
    ostype="linux",
    archtype="arm",
    verbose=QL_VERBOSE.DEBUG
)
ql.reg.cpsr = 0
ql.reg.r0 = 0
ql.reg.r1 = 0
print("registers before starting")
print("r0 = 0x{:x}".format(ql.reg.r0))
print("r1 = 0x{:x}".format(ql.reg.r1))
print("cpsr = 0x{:x}\n".format(ql.reg.cpsr))

for i in range(1, 5, 1):
    ql.run(0, len(shellcode), -1, i)
    print("r0 = 0x{:x}".format(ql.reg.r0))
    print("r1 = 0x{:x}".format(ql.reg.r1))
    print("cpsr = 0x{:x}\n".format(ql.reg.cpsr))
```

emulation  of tst instruction.

```
F:\QILING\testqiling>python armtstop.py
[+]     Profile: Default
[+]     Set init_kernel_get_tls
registers before starting
r0 = 0x0
r1 = 0x0
cpsr = 0x0

r0 = 0x0
r1 = 0x0
cpsr = 0x0

r0 = 0x1
r1 = 0x0
cpsr = 0x0

r0 = 0x1
r1 = 0x6
cpsr = 0x0

r0 = 0x1
r1 = 0x6
cpsr = 0x40000000 <<<<<<<<<<
```

Comment: Oh now I understand. With `CMP` you have to subtract between the two registers for you to get the result and hence update the cpsr flags. But with the instructions with  `S` suffix the result is used to update the flags whether the instructions was `ANDS`, `SUBS`, etc.... But what i dont really get in this concept is how does this really work in `EQ` and `NE` condition codes since there was no comparison done. Please see update in question for the example.

Comment: have You Opened the Link i posted ? have you read the contents ? especially the conditional code execution part ?  have you given a thought to how tst is equivalent to ands operation and what might be the actual result of such operation ?  have you noticed the footnote that says tst discards the result and updates the flags ?

Comment: Thanks I now understand. I read it before but didn't get the S suffix part. I guess I needed the recap.